# How to fill in a text field with drop down selection

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down with different strings, I want a text box to be filled in with the string of the drop down selected.

I am writing this in html

```
<td align="right">
        <select name="xyz" size="1">
          <option value=""></option>
          <?php foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
            <?if($comment->x!= 0):?>
              <option value="<?=$comment->x;?>"<?=($comment->x == $postData["xyz"] ? 'selected="selected"':"")?>>
                   <?=$comment->y;?>
              </option>
            <?endif;?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <textarea name="xz" cols="36" rows="3"><?=$postData["xz"];?></textarea>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/kchRh/)?

HTML:

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="text1">text1</option>
    <option value="text2">text2</option>
    <option value="text3">text3</option>
    <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

    mydropdown.onchange = function(){
          mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value; //to appened
         //mytextbox.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: great answer! Why is the text box draggable though?

Comment: @LukeLandwalker it's draggable by default

Comment: that works, now what can i do to make sure it still works if a user types something in the text box

Comment: @LukeLandwalker you can disable draggable on textarea by `resize: none;` in the CSS

Comment: but if a user types something after a dropdown selection is selected it will not work

Comment: @user570098 so u want them to append give me one sec

Comment: hey guys im still looking for some help, i got the drop down to fill in the text box, but say i edit that box after it was filled in, a new drop down cant overwrite it, how do i fix this?

Comment: @user570098 do you mind create a new question. this was few weeks ago i don't remember much

Comment: I'm a little lost myself, Ill look into it

Comment: @user do you mean like if user edit the textfield then click drop down - it should clear out the textfield?

Comment: yes and also if the use selects a dropdown that fills the text field, then appends to, but realizes they want to start over, by clicking the dropdown again

Comment: @user570098 be easier to have a 'reset' button for the textfield.  Seems to be too much of complexity for such a simple functionality.

Comment: @kjy112 What I am doing wrong here.. I am trying this same code and it is not working for me.. i copy and paste the whole thing...

Comment: @user3713336 have you check your browser console for errors? If you want, setup a jsfiddle and link back to this thread and i can take a look at it.