# load text file contents into text field based on menu selection

Tags: javascript, html, perl, drop-down-menu, cgi

I am trying to do the same thing this user intended:

[How to fill in a text field with drop down selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263839/how-to-fill-in-a-text-field-with-drop-down-selection)

and it works great. Except the "value" of my dropdown menu item is a local path (on linux server) to a text file and instead of printing out that path I want to load the actual contents of the text file.

instead of loading the value directly

```
 mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value; //to appened
```

I want to load the file (which is on the server not client) this.value (eg /var/files/myfile.txt) points to.

My searches reveal that JS is not able to do this, but I am hoping there is an easy way to do this.

** i should mention this is HTML formatted inside a perl-cgi script

Comment: do a little research on AJAX type libraries, like Jquery.  They should have capacity to handle content from a text file and load up into javascript function.

Comment: HTML5 gives you a way to load local files. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: is the value returned from <input type="file" ..> any different from a path string?

Comment: Create a JSON object for each file like: var fileA = {"content": "Paste the file here"} then access that files contents like fileA.content

Comment: If you use JSON and a Perl script (or any other server-side script for that matter), make sure not to tell it to just open, read and print any path it is passed. You will create a **huge security risk** that way! Instead, either give the files numbers and build it so the file reading script knows these, or better yet let it check the paths it receives extensively. For example, it must not open stuff starting with a `/`, or paths containing `..`. That way, an intruder could get to sensible data like server config or password files. He could also execute code like `rm -rf /` with his param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlhttpRequest is the only thing that worked by using xmlhttp.open and xmlhttp.send