# Drop Down menu not opening

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Im trying to figure out why my Drop Down menu is not working. It does appear but when i click on it, it doesn't drop down. Any help would be highly appreciated,
Thanks!
Im trying to figure out why my Drop Down menu is not working. It does appear but when i click on it, it doesn't drop down. Any help would be highly appreciated,
Thanks!

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="location" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Job Location</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<select id="location" name="job_location" multiple="" data-placeholder="Enter city and country or leave it blank" class="form-control form-control-chosen jform-chosen-validate" style="display: none;">

<option value="aichach">Aichach</option>
<option value="allende">Allende</option>
<option value="atlanta">Atlanta</option>
<option value="bangalore">bangalore</option>
<option value="berlin">Berlin</option>
<option value="bristol">bristol</option>
<option value="calgary">Calgary</option>
<option value="california">California</option>
<option value="campuchia">Campuchia</option>
<option value="carapicuiba-sao-paulo">Carapicuíba - São Paulo</option>
<option value="conakry">Conakry</option>
<option value="dallas">Dallas</option>
<option value="dubai">Dubai</option>
<option value="fortaleza">Fortaleza</option>
<option value="guinea">Guinea</option>
<option value="ha-noi">Ha Noi</option>
<option value="hamburg">Hamburg</option>
<option value="india">india</option>
<option value="istanbul">istanbul</option>
<option value="jacksonville">Jacksonville</option>
<option value="kathmandu">Kathmandu</option>
<option value="kk">kk</option>
<option value="latur">latur</option>
<option value="lll">lll</option>
<option value="london">London</option>
<option value="manila">Manila</option>
<option value="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
<option value="montreal">montreal</option>
<option value="new-york">New York</option>
<option value="newcastle">Newcastle</option>
<option value="nigeria">Nigeria</option>
<option value="noordwijk">Noordwijk</option>
<option value="philippines">Philippines</option>
<option value="san-gwann">San Gwann</option>
<option value="scotland">Scotland</option>
<option value="sydney">Sydney</option>
<option value="tourcoin">Tourcoin</option>
<option value="vienna-austria">Vienna, Austria</option>
<option value="wroclaw">Wrocław</option>
<option value="zxczxc">zxczxc</option>
<option value="zxczxvzxv">zxczxvzxv</option>

</select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 795px;" title="" id="location_chosen"><ul class="chosen-choices"><li class="search-field">
<input type="text" value="Enter a city and country or leave it blank" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 279px;"></li></ul><div class="chosen-drop"><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks a ton Rachel :)

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you're welcome. the checkmark will appear when you hover beside the answer. when you click it it turns green :)

Answer (score 1):

you have style display:none on it change it to block

or you could opt for a (small bit of js) option and go for this

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ges7hxof/)

```js
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('country');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

mydropdown.onchange = function(){
    mytextbox.value= " ";
     mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value;
}
```

```css
textarea, select{display:block; vertical-align:top;  height:27px;}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
<option value="aichach">Aichach</option>
<option value="allende">Allende</option>
<option value="atlanta">Atlanta</option>
<option value="bangalore">bangalore</option>
<option value="berlin">Berlin</option>
<option value="bristol">bristol</option>
<option value="calgary">Calgary</option>
<option value="california">California</option>
<option value="campuchia">Campuchia</option>
<option value="carapicuiba-sao-paulo">Carapicuíba - São Paulo</option>
<option value="conakry">Conakry</option>
<option value="dallas">Dallas</option>
<option value="dubai">Dubai</option>
<option value="fortaleza">Fortaleza</option>
<option value="guinea">Guinea</option>
<option value="ha-noi">Ha Noi</option>
<option value="hamburg">Hamburg</option>
<option value="india">india</option>
<option value="istanbul">istanbul</option>
<option value="jacksonville">Jacksonville</option>
<option value="kathmandu">Kathmandu</option>
<option value="kk">kk</option>
<option value="latur">latur</option>
<option value="lll">lll</option>
<option value="london">London</option>
<option value="manila">Manila</option>
<option value="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
<option value="montreal">montreal</option>
<option value="new-york">New York</option>
<option value="newcastle">Newcastle</option>
<option value="nigeria">Nigeria</option>
<option value="noordwijk">Noordwijk</option>
<option value="philippines">Philippines</option>
<option value="san-gwann">San Gwann</option>
<option value="scotland">Scotland</option>
<option value="sydney">Sydney</option>
<option value="tourcoin">Tourcoin</option>
<option value="vienna-austria">Vienna, Austria</option>
<option value="wroclaw">Wrocław</option>
<option value="zxczxc">zxczxc</option>
<option value="zxczxvzxv">zxczxvzxv</option>

</select>

<textarea id="country"></textarea>
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263839/how-to-fill-in-a-text-field-with-drop-down-selection)

Comment: well even if i go for block or inline, the option is not being selected, instead it is just highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

removing the display:none
according to your code you are using bootstrap after removing it if it not working check the jquery and javascript links pattern
like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```