# Selected Text in new line with drop down menu

Tags: javascript

I want to make some drop down menu and get the code from here:

[How to fill in a text field with drop down selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263839/how-to-fill-in-a-text-field-with-drop-down-selection)

http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/kchRh/

HTML:

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="text1">text1</option>
    <option value="text2">text2</option>
    <option value="text3">text3</option>
    <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

    mydropdown.onchange = function(){
          mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value; //to appened
         //mytextbox.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
</script>
```

But I want the new text after another have to be inserted into new line of text area, none the same line with previous selected option.

Any help is appreciated. Thank everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Look Into The JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/s293s7cz/

```
mydropdown.onchange = function(){
     if(!mytextbox.value)
     mytextbox.value = this.value; //first case or else you will have a newline at first 
     else
     mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + '\n' + this.value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help, everyone :) I accept this answer because of jsfiddle link. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly add the new line:

```
mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + "\n" + this.value;
```

If you don't want a blank line to be added upon adding the first entry to the textarea then code for that:

```
if(mytextbox.value) {
  mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + "\n" + this.value;
} else {
  mytextbox.value = this.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in such a way also.

```
 mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value +"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a "\r\n" to insert the new line

```
mydropdown.onchange = function(){
     mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + "\r\n" + this.value;
}
```

You have just to verify the first item to not insert a new line até first place